# SQL extract float value from string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Is there a way to isolate float value from string directly in SQL Server?

I have tried the solution from [Extract float from String/Text SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116769/extract-float-from-string-text-sql-server) but to no avail. Much appreciated!

```
SELECT strCondition, Amount1, Amount2, Amount3
FROM Datatable
WHERE Date >= '2018-04-01'
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

The current strCondition outputs are similar to:

`"2.8, TEXT", "TEXT, 2.8", "TEXT 2.8"`

and other variations.

How would I get it to output "2.8" only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not 100% clear but I know you can use [PatternSplitCM](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/splitting-strings-based-on-patterns) for this type of thing:

**This:**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000) = '"2.8, TEXT", "TEXT, 2.8", "TEXT 2.8"';

SELECT s.Item
FROM   dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string,'[0-9.]') AS s
WHERE  s.[Matched] = 1 AND TRY_CAST(s.item AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL;
```

**Returns:**

```
Item
-------
2.8
2.8
2.8
```

You can add a TOP (1) to get the first one if you only need one.

**This:**

```
DECLARE @datatable TABLE (dID INT IDENTITY, strCondition VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @datatable(strCondition) 
VALUES ('Sometext... blah blah... 20191108 blah blah...'),('"More stuff 22.44","ggooggoo"');

SELECT d.strCondition, Item
FROM   @datatable AS d
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP(1) s.Item
  FROM     dbo.PatternSplitCM(d.strCondition,'[0-9.]') AS s
  WHERE  s.[Matched] = 1 AND TRY_CAST(s.item AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY ItemNumber
) AS s;
```

**Will Return:**

```
strCondition                                            Item
------------------------------------------------------- ---------
Sometext... blah blah... 20191108 blah blah...          20191108
"More stuff 22.44","ggooggoo"                           22.44
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind converting to MONEY (4 decimals) which is a little more forgiving

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'2.8, TEXT')
,(2,'TEXT, 2.8')
,(3,'TEXT 2.8')

Select A.*
      ,SomeVal = try_convert(money,value) 
 from @YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(SomeCol,' ') B
 Where try_convert(money,value) is not null
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeCol     SomeVal
1   2.8, TEXT   2.80
2   TEXT, 2.8   2.80
3   TEXT 2.8    2.80
```